# I'm unable to RUN custom extension script in Azure

Tags: azure

I have single line script which needs run from custom extension script but deployment giving errors.

```
new-item c:\code -ItemType Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

**Error**

```
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.31] [INFO] Temporary directory for event files was successfully created: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.33] [INFO] Space available in event directory: 39981250B
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.33] [INFO] Setting event reporting interval to 10000ms
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.33] [INFO] Event polling is starting...
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.34] [INFO] An ExtensionEventLogger was created
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.34] [INFO] Starting IaaS ScriptHandler Extension v1
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.36] [INFO] HandlerEnvironment = Version: 1, HandlerEnvironment: [LogFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12", ConfigFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\RuntimeSettings", StatusFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status", EventsFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events", HeartbeatFile: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status\HeartBeat.Json"]
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.36] [INFO] Comamnd Executed: enable
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.36] [INFO] Enabling Handler
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.36] [INFO] Successfully enabled TLS.
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.38] [INFO] Handler successfully enabled
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.38] [INFO] Loading configuration for sequence number 2
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.39] [INFO] Handler Configuration
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.42] [INFO] Downloading files specified in configuration...
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.50] [FATAL] Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent.Plugins.CustomScriptHandler.Downloader.DownloadManager+DownloaderException: invalid uri fileUri_{1}
invalid uri fileUri_{2}

   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent.Plugins.CustomScriptHandler.Downloader.DownloadManager.GetUriForDownloadAndLogging(IList`1 uriStrings, Boolean isFileUrisProtected)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent.Plugins.CustomScriptHandler.Downloader.DownloadManager.DownloadFiles(IList`1 fileUriStrs, ProtectedSettings protectedSettings, String downloadDir, Boolean isFileUrisProtected)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent.Plugins.CustomScriptHandler.Program.Main(String[] args)
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.52] [INFO] {"sequenceNumber":2,"totalDuration":376,"status":"error","code":1,"filesDownloaded":0,"durationOfFileDownload":5,"durationOfDownloadHashing":0,"statusFileAccessed":2,"operation":"enable","operationDuration":16,"operationResult":"success","operationSizeOfOutput":0,"operationSizeOfError":0,"sha256HashOfCommandToExecute":null,"downloadSummary":{"downloadUris":null,"fileHashes":null}}
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.52] [INFO] Event processing is terminating...
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.53] [VERBOSE] Attempting to create a new event file...
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.53] [INFO] Successfully created new event file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795225005370320.json
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.53] [VERBOSE] Clearing out event queue for processing...
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.55] [INFO] Successfully wrote events to file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795225005370320.json
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.56] [INFO] Successfully moved event file to event directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\132795225005370320.json
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.56] [INFO] Successfully deleted directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[5416+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:15:00.56] [INFO] Event processing has terminated
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.88] [INFO] Temporary directory for event files was successfully created: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.90] [INFO] Space available in event directory: 39981250B
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.91] [INFO] Setting event reporting interval to 10000ms
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.91] [INFO] Event polling is starting...
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.93] [INFO] An ExtensionEventLogger was created
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.93] [INFO] Starting IaaS ScriptHandler Extension v1
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.93] [INFO] HandlerEnvironment = Version: 1, HandlerEnvironment: [LogFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12", ConfigFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\RuntimeSettings", StatusFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status", EventsFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events", HeartbeatFile: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status\HeartBeat.Json"]
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.94] [INFO] Comamnd Executed: install
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.94] [INFO] Installing Handler
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.94] [INFO] Handler successfully installed
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.94] [INFO] Removing user-level access rules for 2 directories
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.96] [INFO] Removing Users access rules from directory 'C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12'
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.98] [INFO] Removing Users access rules from directory 'C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12'
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:19.99] [INFO] Finished removing user-level access rules
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:20.04] [INFO] {"sequenceNumber":0,"totalDuration":280,"status":null,"code":0,"filesDownloaded":0,"durationOfFileDownload":0,"durationOfDownloadHashing":0,"statusFileAccessed":0,"operation":"install","operationDuration":45,"operationResult":"success","operationSizeOfOutput":0,"operationSizeOfError":0,"sha256HashOfCommandToExecute":null,"downloadSummary":{"downloadUris":null,"fileHashes":null}}
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:20.04] [INFO] Event processing is terminating...
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:20.04] [VERBOSE] Attempting to create a new event file...
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:20.05] [INFO] Successfully created new event file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795227600437451.json
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:20.05] [VERBOSE] Clearing out event queue for processing...
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:20.07] [INFO] Successfully wrote events to file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795227600437451.json
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:20.09] [INFO] Successfully moved event file to event directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\132795227600437451.json
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:20.09] [INFO] Successfully deleted directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[4868+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:20.09] [INFO] Event processing has terminated
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.58] [INFO] Temporary directory for event files was successfully created: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.60] [INFO] Space available in event directory: 39977602B
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.61] [INFO] Setting event reporting interval to 10000ms
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.61] [INFO] Event polling is starting...
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.61] [INFO] An ExtensionEventLogger was created
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.63] [INFO] Starting IaaS ScriptHandler Extension v1
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.63] [INFO] HandlerEnvironment = Version: 1, HandlerEnvironment: [LogFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12", ConfigFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\RuntimeSettings", StatusFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status", EventsFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events", HeartbeatFile: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status\HeartBeat.Json"]
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.63] [INFO] Comamnd Executed: install
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.64] [INFO] Installing Handler
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.64] [INFO] Handler successfully installed
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.64] [INFO] Removing user-level access rules for 2 directories
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.66] [INFO] Removing Users access rules from directory 'C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12'
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.67] [INFO] Removing Users access rules from directory 'C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12'
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.69] [INFO] Finished removing user-level access rules
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.74] [INFO] {"sequenceNumber":0,"totalDuration":277,"status":null,"code":0,"filesDownloaded":0,"durationOfFileDownload":0,"durationOfDownloadHashing":0,"statusFileAccessed":0,"operation":"install","operationDuration":47,"operationResult":"success","operationSizeOfOutput":0,"operationSizeOfError":0,"sha256HashOfCommandToExecute":null,"downloadSummary":{"downloadUris":null,"fileHashes":null}}
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.74] [INFO] Event processing is terminating...
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.74] [VERBOSE] Attempting to create a new event file...
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.75] [INFO] Successfully created new event file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795227617422173.json
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.75] [VERBOSE] Clearing out event queue for processing...
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.77] [INFO] Successfully wrote events to file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795227617422173.json
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.78] [INFO] Successfully moved event file to event directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\132795227617422173.json
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.78] [INFO] Successfully deleted directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[2276+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:21.78] [INFO] Event processing has terminated
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.30] [INFO] Temporary directory for event files was successfully created: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.30] [INFO] Space available in event directory: 39973954B
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.32] [INFO] Setting event reporting interval to 10000ms
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.32] [INFO] Event polling is starting...
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.34] [INFO] An ExtensionEventLogger was created
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.34] [INFO] Starting IaaS ScriptHandler Extension v1
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.34] [INFO] HandlerEnvironment = Version: 1, HandlerEnvironment: [LogFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12", ConfigFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\RuntimeSettings", StatusFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status", EventsFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events", HeartbeatFile: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status\HeartBeat.Json"]
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.35] [INFO] Comamnd Executed: update
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.35] [INFO] Updating Handler
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.35] [INFO] Handler successfully updated
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.37] [INFO] Removing user-level access rules for 2 directories
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.37] [INFO] Removing Users access rules from directory 'C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12'
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.38] [INFO] Removing Users access rules from directory 'C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12'
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.40] [INFO] Finished removing user-level access rules
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.45] [INFO] {"sequenceNumber":0,"totalDuration":278,"status":null,"code":0,"filesDownloaded":0,"durationOfFileDownload":0,"durationOfDownloadHashing":0,"statusFileAccessed":0,"operation":"update","operationDuration":47,"operationResult":"success","operationSizeOfOutput":0,"operationSizeOfError":0,"sha256HashOfCommandToExecute":null,"downloadSummary":{"downloadUris":null,"fileHashes":null}}
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.45] [INFO] Event processing is terminating...
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.46] [VERBOSE] Attempting to create a new event file...
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.46] [INFO] Successfully created new event file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795227994662379.json
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.46] [VERBOSE] Clearing out event queue for processing...
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.48] [INFO] Successfully wrote events to file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795227994662379.json
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.49] [INFO] Successfully moved event file to event directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\132795227994662379.json
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.49] [INFO] Successfully deleted directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[4032+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:19:59.49] [INFO] Event processing has terminated
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:33.98] [INFO] Temporary directory for event files was successfully created: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.00] [INFO] Space available in event directory: 39970312B
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.00] [INFO] Setting event reporting interval to 10000ms
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.01] [INFO] Event polling is starting...
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.01] [INFO] An ExtensionEventLogger was created
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.03] [INFO] Starting IaaS ScriptHandler Extension v1
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.03] [INFO] HandlerEnvironment = Version: 1, HandlerEnvironment: [LogFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12", ConfigFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\RuntimeSettings", StatusFolder: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status", EventsFolder: "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events", HeartbeatFile: "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Status\HeartBeat.Json"]
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.03] [INFO] Comamnd Executed: update
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.04] [INFO] Updating Handler
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.04] [INFO] Handler successfully updated
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.04] [INFO] Removing user-level access rules for 2 directories
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.06] [INFO] Removing Users access rules from directory 'C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12'
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.08] [INFO] Removing Users access rules from directory 'C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12'
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.09] [INFO] Finished removing user-level access rules
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.14] [INFO] {"sequenceNumber":0,"totalDuration":295,"status":null,"code":0,"filesDownloaded":0,"durationOfFileDownload":0,"durationOfDownloadHashing":0,"statusFileAccessed":0,"operation":"update","operationDuration":51,"operationResult":"success","operationSizeOfOutput":0,"operationSizeOfError":0,"sha256HashOfCommandToExecute":null,"downloadSummary":{"downloadUris":null,"fileHashes":null}}
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.14] [INFO] Event processing is terminating...
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.15] [VERBOSE] Attempting to create a new event file...
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.15] [INFO] Successfully created new event file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795228341584227.json
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.15] [VERBOSE] Clearing out event queue for processing...
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.17] [INFO] Successfully wrote events to file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp\132795228341584227.json
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.18] [INFO] Successfully moved event file to event directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\132795228341584227.json
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.18] [INFO] Successfully deleted directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\Events\Temp
[6240+00000001] [10/24/2021 04:20:34.20] [INFO] Event processing has terminated
```

I did already storage script access to blob container --> Overview --> Change access level --> Container (anonymous read access for containers and blobs) but still it's script is not running.

I don't have azure ad.

Comment: This seems more like an Azure problem, not powershell related. It says "invalid uri", have you checked your uri? Maybe you should include that in your question.

Comment: Please add the ARM template to the question